# BeautifulSoup AttributeError after scraping the last "Next Page"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

It iterates through all 20 "next pages" but at the end does not hit the "else" statement to signify no more pages and throws the following:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" on line 38 which is where the if statement is.

```
while True:
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
blabbermouth_articles = soup.find_all('article', {'class': 'category-news'})
# print(response)

for blabbermouth_article in blabbermouth_articles:
    image = blabbermouth_article.find('img').get('src')
    title = blabbermouth_article.find('a').get('title')
    shortLink = blabbermouth_article.find('a').get('href')
    print(title)
    link = "https://www.blabbermouth.net" + shortLink
    print(link)
    print(image)

    article_no += 1
    all_blabbermouth_articles[article_no] = [image, title, link]

next_page_tag = soup.find('a', {'class': 'next_page'})
if next_page_tag.get('href'):
    url = 'https://www.blabbermouth.net' + next_page_tag.get('href')
    print(url)
else:
    print("END OF LAST PAGE")
    break
```

Comment: Your if is not checking agains next_page actually existing. You need to have `if next_page and next_page_tag.get('href'):` instead of what's there now in order for it to go into the esle statement on last page.

Comment: Thanks, 'if next_page_tag and next_page_tag.get('href'):' Works perfectly!